# The best way to delete 5K rows from Innodb table with 30M rows

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, sql-delete, large-data

table:

- foreign_id_1
- foreign_id_2
- integer
- date1
- date2
- primary(foreign_id_1, foreign_id_2)

Query: `delete from table where (foreign_id_1 = ? or foreign_id_2 = ?) and date2 < ?`

Without date query takes about 40 sec. That's too high :( With date much more longer..

The options are:

- <s>`create` another table and `insert` `select`, then `rename`</s>
- <s>use limit and run query multiple times</s>
- split query to run for `foreign_id_1` then `foreign_id_2`
- use select then delete by single row

Is there any faster way?

---

```
mysql> explain select * from compatibility where user_id = 193 or person_id = 193 \G
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: compatibility
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id
          key: PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id
      key_len: 4,4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using union(PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id); Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from compatibility where (user_id = 193 or person_id = 193) and updated_at < '2010-12-02 22:55:33' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: compatibility
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id
          key: PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id
      key_len: 4,4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using union(PRIMARY,compatibility_person_id_user_id); Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post the results of an `EXPLAIN` on your query.  My money is on insufficient indexing.

Comment: Added query explanations

Comment: Combination of options 3 and 4 is a nice way to do it, provided your SELECTS were sufficiently fast.  Can't go wrong with PK deletes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now data amount is 40M (+33%) and rapidly growing. So I've started looking for other, some no-sql, solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having an `OR` in your `WHERE` makes MySQL reluctant (if not completely refuse) to use indexes on your `user_id` and/or `person_id` fields (if there is any -- showing the `CREATE TABLE` would indicate if there was).

If you can add indexes (or modify existing ones since I'm thinking of compound indexes), I'd likely add two:

```
ALTER TABLE compatibility 
ADD INDEX user_id_updated_at (user_id, updated_at),
ADD INDEX persona_id_updated_at (person_id, updated_at);
```

Correspondingly, assuming the rows to `DELETE`  didn't have to be be deleted atomically (i.e. occur at the same instant).

```
DELETE FROM compatibility WHERE user_id = 193 AND updated_at < '2010-12-02 22:55:33';

DELETE FROM compatibility WHERE person_id = 193 AND updated_at < '2010-12-02 22:55:33';
```

Comment: Even the delete has to atomic, this could be accomplished with an InnoDB transaction.

Comment: @ Sonny -- true enough. Re-reading his post, the last idea 'use select then delete by single row', indicates he'd be ok.